# Save password from php form. Which of this is more secure?

Tags: php, md5, registration, salt

```
$pass = substr(md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].microtime().rand(1,100000)),0,6);
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES( '".$username."', '".md5($pass)."')");
```

or

```
$salt = "zfgse5tfgHk2jdf4hGiuyeV9trejkewQ5kjujPhysftf7agfd";
$pass = crypt($password, "$1$".$salt);
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$pass."')");
```

I am saving form data from a php registration form. Which of the above codes is secure? Anything better than these?

Comment: Dont add variebles directly to query, use parameters - http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I personally use [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method #1 will totally break everything, you'll never be able to log in again. Pretty secure (unless you're not escaping `$username`, in which case it's totally worthless), but probably not your intention.

Method #2 will work; but it looks like a little bit of a silly, complicated way of doing something that should be straightforward.

Here's what I usually use:

```
public static function Hash($value) {
    return hash('sha512', hash('sha512', $value) . Config::HashSalt);
}
```

where `Config::HashSalt` is your long, much more random salt string. This needs to be in a class. Here's an example of the structure: https://github.com/minitech/ReTicket/blob/master/config.php

Answer (score 0):

Second option(first is totally wrong), but slightly changed:

1. Use sha512(Never use md5)
2. Use user salt different for every user, but which is stored in db
3. Use server salt, best with some special chars that are not on keyboard
4. Use parameters to insert variables into query([php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php))

Comment: This seems a good option using unique user salt and a server salt.. i'll try this too!